# Volano gli stracci

Tags: meaning, idioms, phrase-origin

Negli ultimi anni sento usare sempre più spesso l'espressione "volano gli stracci": bellissima ed azzeccata per quello che vuole indicare, dà proprio l'idea di una discussione molto accesa, zeppa di insulti ma senza scontro fisico.

Così, incuriosito, mi sono messo a fare una ricerchina in rete per vedere da dove derivi e le risposte che ho trovato non mi convincono:

- [qui la spiegano con lo strappo dei vestiti che accompagna una zuffa.](https://it.quora.com/Quando-c%C3%A8-una-lite-spesso-in-termini-giornalistici-in-tema-di-politica-o-di-gossip-si-usa-dire-sono-volati-gli-stracci-Perch%C3%A9)  
  Ma l'abito strappato non è ancora uno straccio: e comunque per lanciarlo occorrerebbe aver praticamente denudato l'avversario, cosa che non ha molto senso.
- [qui invece la motivano con una critica sociale](https://it.cultura.linguistica.italiano.narkive.com/HM90MdVL/perche-si-usa-il-modo-di-dire-volano-gli-stracci) che, spiegata così com'è, sembra addirittura sottintendere che ad essere lanciate sono le persone stesse: e questo ha ancora meno senso del precedente.

Ora, nessuna delle due spiegazioni mi convince: "volano gli stracci" forma nella mia mente un'immagine da torte in faccia.
Ma mentre le torte sono l'espediente comico per eccellenza e qui sarebbero fuori luogo, gli stracci paiono avere una funzione analoga, solo con un'idea di lite verbale: "volano gli stracci" starebbe a dire "volano le maleparole" ma in maniera più colorita.

Così il dubbio rimane: da dove viene questa espressione? E di quali stracci si tratta?

Comment: La prima spiegazione mi sembra più verosimile: è vero che un vestito strappato non è uno straccio ma si può considerare "straccio" il lembo strappato da un vestito, quindi in una collutazione in cui due persone si accapigliano, stappandosi brani dei rispettivi abiti, letterlmente "volano gli stracci".

Comment: Secan, grazie della risposta: come spiegazione però mi sembra ancora forzata, ci sono troppi passaggi in mezzo. Lite=>mani addosso =>abiti strappati=>pezze di tessuto che volano=>volano gli stracci. In questo caso ci sarebbe violenza fisica e non solo verbale, così non avrebbe senso porre l'attenzione sugli stracci (che sono la conseguenza) invece che sui pugni (che sono la causa): in altre parole, non dà l'idea di una zuffa ("volano gli schiaffi" sarebbe già più forte e meglio descriverebbe ciò che sta accadendo). Parere personale, ovviamente.

Comment: Non so, a me fa venire in mente lo stereotipo della "piazzata", in cui si fa un gran baccano, ci si strattona e spintona, ma non ci sono vere e proprie percosse. Quindi una lite che sembra violenta ma in cui le uniche "vittime" sono, appunto, gli stracci.

Comment: Esatto, proprio la "piazzata" viene in mente anche a me! Dal primo collegamento, e dal tuo precedente commento, avevo invece colto un qualcosa di più violento, una discussione che diventa rissa o giù di lì. Vista in questo contesto, l'espressione ha senso e, in mancanza di alternative, me la farò andare bene come spiegazione. Grazie!

Comment: Ho notato spesso origini "povere" nei modi di dire, quindi cercherei nel popolare l'identità di questi "stracci". Mi viene quindi da pensare che possano riferirsi al gesto dello scagliare degli stracci intesi come cenci da cucina. Un tipico scenario di battibecco domestico tra moglie e marito in merito ad un argomento che ha portato gli animi ad accendersi ma senza sfociare in effettiva violenza. Il gesto del "lanciare lo straccio", "frustare con lo straccio", e quindi "far volare gli stracci", potrebbe quindi trovare origine anche in questo scenario popolare.

Comment: Forse è riferito alle liti tra lavandaie, che si tirano l'un l'altra gli stracci, cioè gli abiti da lavare.

Comment: Per qualche motivo questa domanda sembra attirare pseudo-risposte che sono a stento commenti e ripetono solo concetti già espressi nella domanda stessa. Tra attuali (nel momento in cui scrivo) e cancellate ce ne sono almeno quattro. È la maledizione degli stracci?

Comment: Su Google Books trovo un libro del 1917, "Ombre, uomini e animali" in cui si legge, «Ma se anche voi altri uomini avete un proverbio il quale dice che ne le contese gli stracci volano ! Oh ! se volano gli stracci ! Creda a me , che ho esperienza del mondo , e pratica della vita !» -- e altre occorrenze da NGram sembrano riferirsi al fatto che il "volo" sia conseguenza minore di una contesa ("Dice infatti il Colajanni : «Volano gli stracci, volano in aria gli stracci: i piccoli mafiosi ci lasciano le penne ed assieme a loro anche i piccoli favoreggiatori[...]; ma i grossi calibri tornano...")

Answer (score -1):

Negli anni1700,1800 a Roma spesso le liti finivano a coltellate che oltre a ferire tagliavano giacche e camice.
Il detto era un'avvertimento: " se non riterate l'offesa,qui va a finì che volano gli stracci"

Comment: Puoi dare una fonte?

Answer (score -1):

La mia interpretazione e' simile. Nella roma del 700-800 i coletelli venivano nascosti negli stracci che venivano buttati quando bisognava tirare fuori il pezzo. Quando volavano gli stracci significava che erano i coltelli a parlare.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Suggeriamo di provare a leggere le pagine [tour] e [help] e di dare un'occhiata alle altre domande e risposte per capire come il sito funziona. Non è un forum, ma un sito di domande e risposte. Quello che si aspetta di una risposta non è un'opinione personale. Non esitare a chiedere aiuto se ne hai bisogno.